# Reading data from a file to an object?

Tags: java, filereader

Ok another question about my program that I'm writing called "Flight." In my tester I am creating an object from the Flight class called myFlight. The object has several fields (flight name, miles traveled, etc) but what I'm doing is reading the data from a file called input.txt and trying to put it into the object that I created. There are five lines of information on the file that I'm reading. For some reason I can't quite get it right, if anyone could help me fix this problem I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is the Constructor that has all the fields from my Flight class:

```
 public Flight(String name, int num, int miles, String origin, String destination)
  {
    Airlinename = name;
    flightnumber = num;
    numofmiles = miles;
    Origincity = origin;
    Destinationcity = destination;
  }
```

And the part of my program where I created the object and try to read the data from the file. I had created a blank constructor in my class too because I wasn't sure if I was supposed to put anything in the object when I created it.

```
Flight myFlight = new Flight();

    File myFile = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
      myFlight = inputFile.nextLine();
    }

    inputFile.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide how does your txt file looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you use special characters, you need to modify your program so you can read them correctly.

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile, "UTF-8");
```

On the other hand, if the text file contains the following, possibly subsequent calls to `nextInt()` generate a runtime exception.

```
Gran España
1
1001
New York
Los Angeles
```

If that were the case, the reading should be different.

```
myFlight = new Flight(inputFile.nextLine(), 
           Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine()), 
           Integer.parseInt(inputFile.nextLine()), 
           inputFile.nextLine(), 
           inputFile.nextLine());
```

As with any program, when adding more conditions to improve the model, it needs more and more code.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
myFlight = new Flight(inputFile.next(), inputFile.nextInt(), 
           inputFile.nextInt(), inputFile.next(), inputFile.next());
```

Comment: it keeps telling me that it can't find the file (input.txt) ?

Comment: check that the file exists in the same directory as the java program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly assign a string line to an object, you need to parse the line into parts and assign values to variables one by one.

Answer (score 0):

How is your input text organized? The Scanner's `nextLine()` method is returning a String object and definitely you cannot assign that to a type Flight. There are different methods to get the different values in the Scanner like `nextInt(), nextFloat()`.

Basically you can try like this

```
Flight myFlight = new Flight();
myFlight.setFlightName(inputFile.next());
myflight.setMiles(inputFile.nextInt();
```

etc.

This is just a sample, you need to check the format you have in the input.txt file.

Comment: this is what my input file looks like (all on different lines): American Airlines
56
Chicago
New York
780

Comment: Basically you can format the input text in a different format like American Airlines|56|Chicago|New York|780, the delimiting character is the pipeling symbol. Since delimiting with spaces may not give you the right values because the airline is "American Airlines", suppose if you delimit with space you will not get the whole name. Now you can check the Scanner class API documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File) to get more information.

Comment: If you have each item in a different line, then your file contain only one airline details or multiple. If multiple then how do you  differentiate the end of one record. If each line is one record then you can do the formatting the way i told with a delimiter so that you get an array of Flight instances each represents one line from the file. hope it helps

Comment: ok so it seems to work now, it compiles and all but now when I run it I get an error that the file was not found. I have the file names correct and it is saved on my computer in a notepad file under the name input.txt any ideas?

Comment: Check the path of the file. If you placed the file in the same location where you run the java program then it will pick it up else you need to give the path when creating `new File()`

Comment: oh ok so it finds the file now but I'm still get these run time errors for the code that I have                                     at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10991/discussion-between-andrew-and-raddykrish)

Comment: i saw your comments over chat.Glad that my comments helped you.